# How can i restrict or validate input field entering repeated numbers?

Tags: angularjs

[image]

When user enter numbers as shown above I need to show a alert

Comment: How many times do you want a user to repeat a number?

Comment: Say, if user enters 5 times continuously same number, then i need to show an alert saying you have entered same number repeatedly

Comment: It should be configurable

Comment: It's helpful to show the code you have, make an attempt to solve the problem yourself.  For more advice on how to write a good question, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern,this way can help you restrict any digit ({3}-no.of repetitions)

@Pattern(regexp="^(?!(\d)\1{3})")

Comment: How can I give the pattern in html. And also repeated number could be any.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) if you want to show an *alert*:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" id="" value="" />

$scope.$watch('test', function(newValue) {
    if (/(\d)\1{4,}/.test(newValue)) {
      alert('invalid input: ' + newValue) 
    }
  })
```

If you want to show a red error-border you can use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test2" ng-class="{red:isInvalid(test2)}" />

$scope.isInvalid = function(input) {
    return /(\d)\1{4,}/.test(input)
  }

.red {
  border-color: red;
}
```

You can see [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/SghvBWABr5y7esy3j826?p=preview) an example.

[ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) is another option.